# Highcharts - Parent color in legend

Tags: highcharts

I am attempting to the css color of my legend for my treemap layout.

In my treemap legend I am only displaying the parent's name and color. I would like to do the same but make the parent's name the same color.

For example: low display in blue text, med-low display in green text; while still displaying the color circle next to it.

i've attempted this by using the legend labelFormatter function but it seems to have no affect on my legend.

here is a code snippet of what I tried:

```
    legend: {
        labelFormatter: function () {
          return `<span style="color:${this.parent.color};"> <br/> ${this.parent.name}</span>`;
        }
    },
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrkqo73z/4/) link to the chart :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The legend object cannot be nested in the chart object config.
2. Rendering the as a span needs to set the `legend.useHTML` to true, which allows rendering the legend label as outstanding HTML element which could be styled in this way.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dmy9uqbe/

```
  legend: {
    useHTML: true,
    labelFormatter: function() {
      return `<span style="color:${this.color};"> <br/> ${this.name}</span>`;
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.useHTML